# What would cause the wrong attributes to display after Magento 2 migation?

Tags: attributes, migration, magento-2.1.7

I migrated from Magento 1.9 to 2.1. In my layered navigation almost every attribute shows up for every product. On the item page in the backend there are a bunch of empty attributes, no label or anything. All of the attributes work fine in Magento 1, and I had no issues migrating. How can I fix this? [image]

I figured out that these were attributes such as backorders_leadtime. I don't use them so when I removed them from the attribute set all of these boxes went away. I still haven't figured out why all attributes are showing.

Comment: In such case you should not migrate settings. This happens because you migrated setting too from magento1.9

Comment: Which settings are you referring to?

Comment: In steps of migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this but it is the fix. When we don't have the information it falls we put it as see spec. For example horsepower we can have .5, 1, 2, 3 and if we don't have the information we put it in see spec under horsepower. In Magento 1 all see spec were treated separate. For whatever reason in Magento 2 If one product set has one attribute that is selected as see spec it show everything that has see spec.